# How do you make a (Windows) Form a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms

This might be a fairly easy question to most people, but I am just a beginner and genuinely curious. I am trying to make Form1 (A Windows Form..) into a parameter for a function, as well as this other form (Say, Form2).

I have a class in which has the codes for the most common code for buttons for all forms.

The code I'm trying to currently do is for opening a new form and hiding the previous one:

```
public static void navigationButton(Form currentForm, Form nextForm)
{
    currentForm.Hide();
    nextForm form = new nextForm();
    form.Show();
}
```

The error I get is on `nextForm form = new nextForm()` which says 'nextForm is a variable but is used like a type.'

I'm trying to do this so I do not have to constantly do the three lines of code over and over again and I can just write something like `navigationButton(Form1, Form2)` .

What is the proper way of making a Windows Form a parameter? Or is this idea inefficent?

Comment: form = new Form(); or  Form form = new Form(); You try to create new object of class "nextForm" in your code. But there is no class "nextForm".))) Also your need to pass nextForm by reference in same ways.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dmitriy ! How would I call the function in Form1 though? I tried doing `ButtonControl.navigationButton(this,Form2);` gives me an error saying "'Form2' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.", as I replied to one answer

Comment: yes, ypu'll get this error. If I'm not mistaken, you wanna create "syntax sugar", won't me? So, you need to add "this" in your static method definition ( navigationButton(this Form currentForm, Form nextForm)). Also, what is Form2? Is this a new class or object? You cannot pass a class in function, only object. Also, you strongly need to pass in by out, for example, but I don't member is it possible for WinForms. It should be like this navigationButton(this Form currentForm, out Form nextForm). So, your code should be like this: Form testForm; myForm.navigationButton(out testForm);

Comment: I wrote answer which you could try to implement in your code. So, It also works for all inherited classes from From class, but you need to use Reflection for creation correct type of inherited class of Form.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitriy ! I really appreciate all of this

Comment: Downvoter, please explain as well?

Comment: I'm an upvoter.))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161101/discussion-between-stuart-den-and-dmitriy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give an answer (I can't get 100% of correctness, but...)

So, let's look your code.

```
public static void navigationButton(Form currentForm, Form nextForm)
{
    currentForm.Hide();
    nextForm form = new nextForm();
    form.Show();
}
```

First of all, you have an error in `nextForm form = new nextForm()`, because nextForm is an object of class Form. Second, generated form object will be marked for gc and destroyed in undetermined time/way (so, If I'm not mistaken), because you won't give back any reference on it.
Third, It's better to create "syntax sugar" for your code. 
So, let's rewrite it in possible way:

```
public static void NavigationButton(this Form currentForm, out Form nextForm)
{
    currentForm.Hide();
    nextForm = new Form();
    nextForm.Show();
}
```

You could call your code in the same manner:

```
Form testForm;
myForm.NavigationButton(out testForm);
```

Update 1:
In C# 7.0 you could write last part of code in the same manner:

```
myForm.NavigationButton(out Form testForm);
```

Update 2:
If you want to create "widespread" syntax sugar, use code like this:

```
    public static void NavigationButton<T>(this Form currentForm, out Form nextForm) where T: Form
{
    currentForm.Hide();
    nextForm = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    nextForm.Show();
}
```

with `myForm.NavigationButton<Form2>(out Form2 testForm);` (this is for C#7.0) or

```
Form2 testForm;
myForm.NavigationButton<Form2>(out testForm);
```

in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use the second form parameter, like this:

```
public static void Navigate(Form currentForm, Form nextForm)
{
    currentForm.Hide();
    nextForm.Show();
}
```

And you should then call it something like this:

```
Navigate(activeForm, new Form2());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have tried it but I get an error when I call it in Form1.cs. `ButtonControl.navigationButton(this,Form2);` gives me an error saying "'Form2' is a type, which is not valid in the given context."

Comment: @Stuart Den Also, It's a good idea to make "syntax sugar" like "public static void navigationButton(this Form currentForm, Form nextForm)" for rewriting Peter B code in 1 string currentForm.navigationButton(nextForm).

Comment: @PeterB So, what about gc? Will this code work well without any references on created Form2 in code?

Comment: The code will work, but if you plan on using the Form2 object anywhere else (if only to pass it to `Navigate()` to close it and open yet another form) then you'll need to keep the object in a variable or property of your liking.

Comment: @Dmitriy gc will not clear objects currently shown on the UI... they are in use, even if you don't save them in a variable, simply because they are running their own UI code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have two forms; we'll call them formIndex and formNext.

If I understood you correctly, you have a button in formIndex, which is clicked on and then a new window opens. We'll call the button button1.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // User clicks on button, close this form, open next
    NavigateToNextForm(this, new FormNext(this)); 
    // Call next method with instance of current object and new form
    // Passing current instance to next form, so we can navigate back
}

internal void NavigateToNextForm(Form formIndex, Form formNext) {
    // Assuming you want to return back to this form,
    // we'll just hide the window
    formIndex.Hide();

    // Now we'll show the next one
    formNext.Show();
}
```

---

Of course, depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you may want to wait until the next form has closed (and possibly returned a DialogResult).

In which case, you could use the async-await model and Task.Run(Action).